# Logarithmic spiral tangent when starting at radius 0

Tags: polar-coordinates, tangent-line

I have a logarithmic spiral of the form $$r=ce^{a\theta}-c$$
Subtracting by $c$ modifies the spiral such that $r(0)=0$.

How do I calculate the slope of the tangent line at a point $(r(\theta),\theta)$?

You can calculate the slope of the tangent line to any polar curve at a given point by using differential calculus like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Differential_calculus, but I was wondering if it could not be done simpler in this case by for example using this property of logarithmic spirals: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TangentOnALogarithmicSpiral/

Comment: The curve you get [isn't really a spiral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PolarPlot%5BExp%5Bq%5D-1%2C%7Bq%2C-7%2C4%7D%5D)

Comment: @eyeballfrog Not sure what you mean. Try drawing in an interval where $q\geq 0$

Comment: What is $q$ ? Is it $a$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, $\theta$ in his link $\theta$ is called q